# Max function on date giving multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got 3 tables: order, customer and invoice. I need to get the latest invoice number for each customer.

I am using the `max` function on order date  and then grouping by customer number and invoice number, where order status was confirmed or shipped.

```
  select max(o.order_date), c.customer_number, i.invoice_number
  from orders o , invoices i , customer c
  where o.order_oid = i.order_oid
  and c.customer_oid = i.customer_oid
  and o.status_oid in (  4,6)
  group by c.customer_number, i.invoice_number;
```

I am getting duplicate records like:

```
 Date       cust_num    invc#
 1/22/2018   479         I128
 4/23/2018   479         I287
 5/18/2018   479         I433
```

It should have returned me only last record. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are, as you said, grouping by customer_number and invoice number - so you'll get one row for each combination of those two fields. That is what's supposed to happen. What do you actually want to see, a single row per customer with the latest date, showing the invoice number corresponding to that date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description and comments you seem to want:

```
select max(o.order_date), c.customer_number,
  max(i.invoice_number) keep (dense_rank last order by o.order_date) as invoice_number
from orders o , invoices i , customer c
where o.order_oid = i.order_oid
and c.customer_oid = i.customer_oid
and o.status_oid in (  4,6)
group by c.customer_number;
```

The `group by` no longer includes the invoice number; instead the last invoice number, based on date, is found using [`last`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST.html).

If the invoice numbers are strictly in date order, and fixed length, you could potentially just do:

```
select max(o.order_date), c.customer_number, max(i.invoice_number) as invoice_number
```

but if if it's possible to go from say invoice I999 to I1000 then it isn't safe to sort those just as strings, since - as a string 'I1000' will sort before 'I999'.

---

Not related, but you might want to consider moving to modern join syntax:

```
select max(o.order_date), c.customer_number,
  max(i.invoice_number) keep (dense_rank last order by o.order_date) as invoice_number
from orders o
join invoices i on i.order_oid = o.order_oid
join customer c on c.customer_oid = i.customer_oid
where o.status_oid in (4, 6)
group by c.customer_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need max(invoice_number) to avoid getting a record per invoice

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window analytic function

```
select order_date, customer_number, invoice_number
  from   
 (
  select o.order_date, c.customer_number, i.invoice_number, 
         row_number() over (partition by c.customer_number order by o.order_date desc) as rn             
    from orders o 
    join invoices i on o.order_oid = i.order_oid
    join customer c on c.customer_oid = i.customer_oid 
   where o.status_oid in (4,6)
  )
 where rn = 1;
```

**P.S. :** Of course, proper to give up old-style comma seperated join for the queries